# Android app won't push from eclipse/adb to phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S (Epic) with syndicate Rom Frozen 1.2 ROM.

I've developing apps.

When the ROM cooks made the ROM, I think that they left out some important things.  I first had to fix "am" by added the shell to the top.  Now when I try to run apps directly on my device from Eclipse/adb, they won't run.

The last version of the ROM (1.1) ran just fine.  So I think something else must have been screwed up when the cooks made 1.2.

Any ideas on why the ROM doesnt get installed?  What can I check for?  How can I fix this?

```
[2011-09-29 12:39:55 - Drag Racing Workbench] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'D7005af7xxxx'
[2011-09-29 12:39:55 - Drag Racing Workbench] Uploading Drag Racing Workbench.apk onto device 'D7005af7xxxx'
[2011-09-29 12:39:56 - Drag Racing Workbench] Installing Drag Racing Workbench.apk...
[2011-09-29 12:39:56 - Drag Racing Workbench] Success!
[2011-09-29 12:39:56 - Drag Racing Workbench] Starting activity com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage on device D7005af7xxxx
[2011-09-29 12:39:56 - Drag Racing Workbench] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-09-29 12:39:59 - Drag Racing Workbench] Starting activity com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage on device D7005af7xxxx
[2011-09-29 12:40:00 - Drag Racing Workbench] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-09-29 12:40:03 - Drag Racing Workbench] Starting activity com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage on device D7005af7xxxx
[2011-09-29 12:40:03 - Drag Racing Workbench] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-09-29 12:40:06 - Drag Racing Workbench] Starting activity com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage on device D7005af7xxxx
[2011-09-29 12:40:07 - Drag Racing Workbench] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-09-29 12:40:10 - Drag Racing Workbench] Starting activity com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage on device D7005af7xxxx
[2011-09-29 12:40:10 - Drag Racing Workbench] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench/.startPage }
[2011-09-29 12:40:10 - Drag Racing Workbench] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2011-09-29 12:40:10 - Drag Racing Workbench] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench/com.motorcitysoftware.dragracingworkbench.startPage} does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/system/bin/pm and /system/bin/am are broken.  They both need #!/system/bin/sh

to add this manually, from a connected PC

Run:adb shell
Now you are shelled to the device.

run busybox vi /system/bin/pm
and insert the line.  do the same for am.